# Python Dataset module AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: python, dataset

I'm trying to use the `dataset` module in python.

```
import dataset

# connecting to a MySQL database with user and password
db = dataset.connect('mysql://root:Kradz579032!!@localhost/aliexpressapidb')
```

But I keep getting the following  error :

> AttributeError: `module` object has no attribute 'connect'

What does it mean?

Comment: Could you post the full error ? Is there a traceback ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/reezalaq/Downloads/newali/db/dataset.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dataset import connect
  File "/Users/reezalaq/Downloads/newali/db/dataset.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dataset import connect
ImportError: cannot import name connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for posting your Traceback.
The error message shows that you've named your file `dataset.py`:

```
File "/Users/reezalaq/Downloads/newali/db/dataset.py"
```

This [masks the module](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap) you want to import, here `dataset`. To solve this, just rename your file to something else.